# Is there a way, using javascript, to check a website's server/database for changes that were sent and then implement a reload?

Tags: javascript

So what the title says. Can I check a website's server/database (Or whatever it is called, sorry I'm new to coding) for changes made to the website so I can implement a reload and then implement my code.

Comment: Search for "push notifications". Yes you can.

Answer (score 0):

In your site's JavaScript you can make small requests back to your web server without reloading the whole page, then take some action; e.g. change the content on part of your page, or maybe navigate somewhere else. You can choose a specific URL to request data from. The common way to structure things is using [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

The regular part of your site would live at www.example.com/myaccount, etc., and your REST API would live at www.example.com/api/account/posts?dateafter=blah. You can use client-side JS libraries like JQuery to send requests up to your REST API, deserialize the resulting JSON into JS objects, then take action.

On the server side, various frameworks will help you build APIs, with appropriate routing. It depends what kind of hosting, language expertise, etc. that you have.

Comment: I'm not working on my own website I'm trying to see changes on any website for example reddit. I don't want to reload to see if changes were made I want to reload when I "know" changes have been made.

Comment: If you're trying to monitor other sites your best bet is their official API, if they have one. For reddit, take a look at https://www.reddit.com/dev/api.

You can monitor this from your client-side JavaScript and trigger a refresh/navigate or modify content. Or, you can monitor this from your server-side web app and do your own push/pull down to your client side through your own API.